# How to avoid concurrency running in two instances when using schedulers or public synchronized void run()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, glassfish-3

I am using glassfish 3.1.2 build 5. I have two servers and each have 1 cluster. Each cluster have 2 instances. In my J2EE application i have schedulers(Cron Quartx schedulers) which will run every day at night 12 and also simply running below code at 30000(milli secs) interval

```
public synchronized void run() {
 /** Some set of functions **/
/** Calling procedure **/
if count >0{
/** forming xml and updating web service**/
}else {
Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(30000));
}
```

My problem is when i deploy my application as a stand alone instance its running fine . When i deploy the same in above cluster and load balancing structure either i am facing null pointer exception or my applications got processed for 4 times. But it should happen only one for each application ? How to avoid this concurrency ?

Comment: why do you use both quartx scheduler and Thread.sleep?

Comment: Sorry. Thread.sleep is seperate code..Like that in quartz scheduler i am doing some other set of functions not the same functions ..I am facing problem in both..while using schedulers as well as simple syncronized run

Comment: You need to find a lock mechanism which works across the network; `synchronized` only affects the current JVM

Comment: whether we can use annotation to lock public @interface DisallowConcurrentExecution

Comment: You can use `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` or the older `StaefulJob` interface. However this requires that you store the execution state in the database. Else there is no way for node1 to know if node2 is executing the job.

Comment: which job store you are using ?